# App unable to connect to share after a period of time

Tags: .net, connection, network-share

I've got a .NET app monitoring a network share and periodically it loses the connection.

The app itself does not send any login info, it runs under the current (Windows) user.

When this happens I can't connect to the network share in Explorer either, I need to reboot the machine.

Is there any way programmatically in .NET I could get around this very annoying issue (ANGRY CUSTOMERS!)?

Thank you!
Chris

Comment: Does this happen at a single customer site or at mutliple sites? I'm trying to understand if it is an issue with their network.

Comment: Which machine do you have to reboot? The machine that is monitoring the share, or the machine that is hosting the share?

Comment: Thanks guys for your replies. This happens at multiple sites. The machine monitoring the share is the one that needs to be rebooted, perhaps because the machine with the network share gets rebooted.